# Slimming down Symfony2 controller and persist logic

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, symfony, doctrine-orm

From the point of view of MVC pattern and Symfony2, can i slim down my **controller code** just a bit, moving away some **persist logic**? For example, given a standard new action like this:

```
public function newAction(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request)
{

    // Create a new entity and a new form type for managing
    $entity = $this->createNewEntity();
    $form   = $this->createForm($this->createNewFormType(), $entity);

    // If it's GET just return the view
    if('GET' == $request->getMethod())
        return array('form' => $form->createView());

    // It's POST request so bind the form
    $form->bindRequest($request);

    // ... and if it's valid just persist the entity
    if($form->isValid()) :

        $em = $this->getEntityManager(); // Should be carried by controller?
        $em->persist($entity);           // Should be carried by controller?
        $em->flush();                    // Should be carried by controller?

        // Redirect the user to the default page
        return $this->redirect($this->getOnNewSuccessRedirectUrl($entity));

    endif;

    // Return the view plus errors
    return array(
        'errors' => $this->getValidator()->validate($entity),
        'form'   => $form->createView()
    );

}
```

Would be correct moving that **logic to the repository**? An example (warning: may not work):

```
class BaseRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{

    /**
     * Persist the entity (either new or existent)
     *
     * @param object $entity
     */
    public function save($entity)
    {
        $em = $this->_em;
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }

    /**
     * Delete the entity.
     *
     * @param object $entity
     */
    public function delete($entity)
    {
        $em = $this->_em;
        $em->remove($entity);
        $em->flush();
    }

}
```

The controller code would be:

```
if($form->isValid()) :

    $this->getRepository()->save($entity);

    // Redirect the user to the default page
    return $this->redirect($this->getOnNewSuccessRedirectUrl($entity));

endif;
```

Comment: By calling $em->flush($entity); instead of $em->flush(); you're doing only changes for the given entity and relates sub-entities.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it's a good idea to move your persist and remove logic out of your controllers, but the repository is not the correct place for it.

From the Symfony2 docs (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database):

> You can think of a repository as a PHP class whose only job is to help you fetch entities of a certain class.

You should only be using your repository class for fetching data from the database.

I would move your persist/remove logic into a service (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) so your controller code would be something like

```
if($form->isValid()) :

    $this->get('service.entity')->save($entity);

    // Redirect the user to the default page
    return $this->redirect($this->getOnNewSuccessRedirectUrl($entity));

endif;
```

Comment: That's the way to go. The classes performing such tasks are usually called entity Managers (e.g. `MyEntityNameManager`) and can be seen in several Symfony2 bundles ([here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Entity/UserManager.php) and [here](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/blob/2.0/Model/ModelManagerInterface.php) for example).

Comment: I know this is old but I wonder why Symfony went with recommending this pattern. You'll typically see the persist logic in the repository in projects using Entity Framework and Hibernate. Any idea why?

I'm all for SOA but it seems redundant to create a new service for each entity to handle persist logic.

Answer (score 4):

Chris is absolutely right.

But by the way:

Why do you validate you entity again in this way:

'errors' => $this->getValidator()->validate($entity)?

You bind the request to the form, so the errors are processed in the created view in the viewhelpers 'form_errors(...)'.